# How to stop a loop in the command in the Telegram robot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am building a telegram robot with python-telegram-bot
I want to do something in the loop and the user clicks on the menu to stop that command in the loop.

But the back button and menu do not work, so the back button does not work until the loop is finished.

my code

```
def callback_menu(update, context):
    if update.message.text == "menu":
        update = update.message
        key = [[" shopping line"], [" Sales queue"]]
        markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(key, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        update.reply_text('Select', reply_markup=markup)

    if update.message.text == ' shopping line':
        key = [["menu"]]
        markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(key, resize_keyboard=True)
        list = ["saba", "vmelate", "folad", "shasta", "zobe"]
        for i in list:
            if update.message.text!=" shopping line":
                break
            update.message.reply_text('{}shopping line ✅'.format(i), reply_markup=markup)
            time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 4))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, callback_menu))
```

Comment: You stop a loop in the Telegram bot like you stop any loop, by using `break`, which you did. If the loop doesn't stop this means that apparently `update.message.text` has a different value than you expect.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: You could read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/